# How to code this AngularJS hide the button when clicked and then show it after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the HTML code:

```
<button id="btn_hide">Hide Me!</button>
```

And this is jQuery code, which hides the button when clicked and then shows it after 5 seconds. I would like to code this in AngularJS.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btn_hide').click (function() {
        $(this).hide(5000,function () {
            $('#btn_hide').show(5000);
        });  
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<button id="btn_hide" ng-click="hide()" ng-hide="hidden">Hide Me!</button>

$scope.hide = function() {
    $scope.hidden = true;
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.hidden = false;
    }, 5000);
};
```

Comment: thanks men but its not working your codes! Whats the problem with this?

Comment: Its working perfectly fine (+1); you just need to embed the code in an Angular application: http://embed.plnkr.co/NhovgiH9lalkOEBZONdG/preview